# Run groovy script code contained in a string

Tags: java, groovy

I have to implement a java function for my thesis that executes a groovy script and get the result back.
The issue is that the script code is contained into a string. Is there any way to do that without create a new file with the code into it?

Thanks in advance, Giacomo

Comment: Try to follow [these guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) when asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Embedding Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy):

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.setVariable("foo", new Integer(2));
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);

Object value = shell.evaluate("println 'Hello World!'; x = 123; return foo * 10");
```